# tel and mailto Links Stopped Working in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, hottowel

I developing hybrid mobile application with help of cordova.
I am using cordova version 7.0.1, tel & mailto links are not working in android app, below is the code.

```
<a href="tel:+442079398514">+44 20 7939 8514</a> 
<a href="mailto:gsc@travelsecurity.com">gsc@travelsecurity.com</a>
```

for this have update following changes,
added inappbrowser plugin, updated config.xml,

```
<access origin="*" />

<access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />

<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

Please check where I did wrong and let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same bug today.
Fixed it by sending the emails like this:

```
window.open('mailto:john@doe.com?body=test", '_system');
```

Comment: It working for me, thanks @FIZLIN you saved my time.